# Python scripts for monkeyrunner on cyanogenMod

Tags: python, monkeyrunner, cyanogenmod

I have some scripts that run perfectly on htc desire with sense on it. But when I start my scripts on htc desire with cyanogenMod it throws a lot of weird exception. Is anybody familiar with this kind of topic ?

for example I have script that runs entirely good on sense, but on cyanogen it throws exception for time.sleep(10), if I comment this out (on cyanogen) I runs with no exception but if I give some time to sleep it throws

```
120119 14:06:18.555:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice] Error sending touch event: 150 700 DOWN_AND_UP
120119 14:06:18.555:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice]java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
120119 14:06:18.555:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice] at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
120119 14:06:18.555:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice] at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
120119 14:06:18.555:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice] at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
120119 14:06:18.555:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice] at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:202)
120119 14:06:18.555:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice] at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:263)
120119 14:06:18.555:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice] at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:106)
120119 14:06:18.555:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice] at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:190)
120119 14:06:18.555:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbMonkeyDevice] at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(BufferedWriter.java:111)
```

I do not understand why time.sleep throws exception on cyanogen :S . . .

NOTE:
I run the same script on sense and cyanogenMod, in sense work with no problems on cyanogen it trows broken pipe on time.sleep . . .

Thanks

Comment: You should probably tag this with cyanogenmod.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a suggestion. Have you tried with changing the time on your sleep method. sometimes there may be some thread timeout issues. Just try out with 2 or 3 seconds to your sleep method.